# Kapacitor Join using 'on' Property and Single Dimension

Tags: kapacitor

I'm joining streams in Kapacitor using the `on` property. The join only seems to work if one of the streams has multiple `groupBy` dimensions, even if only one dimension is actually needed. Why is that?

For example, in the code below, the join won't return anything if `floor` was removed from `.groupBy('building', 'floor')`. Why doesn't the join work with `building` alone?

```
var building = stream
    |from()
        .measurement('building_power')
        .groupBy('building')
var floor = stream
    |from()
        .measurement('floor_power')
        .groupBy('building', 'floor')
building
    |join(floor)
        .as('building', 'floor')
        .on('building')
```

Comment: Can you give an example? I'm not totally sure I follow what the questions is.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelDesa - I added an example to the question.